# Authenticating a user for a single app with multiple domains

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, forms-authentication, httpcookie

I have one asp.net web application, but two different domains point to this web app. For instance: `www.one.com` and `www.two.com` both point to the same web app.

I have an issue where I need certain pages to be on a specific domain (due to some security requirements from our online payment provider - a third party website). So let's say `page1.aspx` needs to be called on `www.two.com`

The process is as follows:

1. A user logs into `www.one.com`
2. The authentication cookie is saved to the browser
3. The user then navigates to `page1.aspx` and, if on the wrong domain, gets redirected to the correct domain. (this redirection happens on `page1.aspx` in the `page_load` event)
4. Then asp.net redirects the user to the login screen, because the authentication cookie is not sent to `www.two.com`.

How can I track the user and keep him/her logged in between the two domains?

Comment: there is not automatic way for this - you need to made a code that transfer the one to the other, and keep a record of this transfer on the database.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case. Problem is that the page set's a whole bunch of session variables for later use. Meaning I'll have to transfer these between sessions as well. I thought I could maybe just save the logged in user in the database (as you say), and then on the redirect I can just attach (so to speak) the existing session to the user.